# Fontspec/xeCJK AutoFakeBold and copyable Chinese characters in PDF

Tags: fontspec, xecjk

I'm writing a document in mixed English and Chinese (with the `xeCJK` package. I want to add some fake bold headlines using the font Kaiti SC. When I do this using the `AutoFakeBold` option, this makes it unable to copy the characters in the resulting PDF. How can I fix this?

It seems like `xeCJK` is loading `fontspec` behind the curtains, so the issue might be related to it.

Here's a MWE.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont[Scale=1.2, AutoFakeBold=true]{Kaiti SC} % removing the bold makes the output copyable


\begin{document}

\textbf{你好}

宋代大{\color{red}文学家}苏东坡常常一个人出去旅行。他特别喜欢参观寺庙。

\end{document}
```

Comment: In `lualatex` I would use outline via `\pdfliteral`, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169636/proper-outline-in-devanagari-and-arabic-fonts

Comment: AFAIK, that is a bug of XeTeX. We have no idea to solve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Malipivo provided a solution using `\pdfliteral`, and that technique works for XeTeX too. This technique is used in [`zhmCJK`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zhmcjk) package. You can read the documented source code of `zhmCJK` if you are interested in it.

However, it is quite tricky to apply this technique properly in `xeCJK`:

```
% !TeX program = XeLaTeX
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}

\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}

% value > 0
\def\xeCJKembold{0.4}

% hack into xeCJK, you don't need to understand it
\def\saveCJKnode{\dimen255\lastkern}
\def\restoreCJKnode{\kern-\dimen255\kern\dimen255}

% save old definition of \CJKsymbol and \CJKpunctsymbol for CJK output
\let\CJKoldsymbol\CJKsymbol
\let\CJKoldpunctsymbol\CJKpunctsymbol

% apply pdf literal fake bold
\def\CJKfakeboldsymbol#1{%
  \special{pdf:literal direct 2 Tr \xeCJKembold\space w}%
  \CJKoldsymbol{#1}%
  \saveCJKnode
  \special{pdf:literal direct 0 Tr}%
  \restoreCJKnode}
\def\CJKfakeboldpunctsymbol#1{%
  \special{pdf:literal direct 2 Tr \xeCJKembold\space w}%
  \CJKoldpunctsymbol{#1}%
  \saveCJKnode
  \special{pdf:literal direct 0 Tr}%
  \restoreCJKnode}
\newcommand\CJKfakebold[1]{%
  \let\CJKsymbol\CJKfakeboldsymbol
  \let\CJKpunctsymbol\CJKfakeboldpunctsymbol
  #1%
  \let\CJKsymbol\CJKoldsymbol
  \let\CJKpunctsymbol\CJKoldpunctsymbol}

\begin{document}

正常汉字。\CJKfakebold{可复制“伪粗体”汉字。English unchanged. 粗体汉字。}正常汉字。

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the non-CJK characters are unchanged in `\CJKfakebold` command. This is a feature by design. You should use `\textbf` or `\bfseries` as usual for English.

And note that the code above is not at all complete for `xeCJK`, puctuation kerning is wrong for example. It should be implemented more carefully (maybe in a very different way) if we add this feature into the package.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not making a professional document so the kerning is not so important. Is there a way to combine this with the AutoFakeBold setting or should I just adjust the `\xeCJKembold` value manually?

Comment: @pg-robban: Well, I think you can set it manually.

Comment: Alright, I have one more question before I mark the question as answered: Suppose I have a macro which does something with bold text, currently I do this with `\textbf{#1}` on that part. Is there any way I can find out if the argument consists of only Chinese characters so that I can apply the correct bold function (`\textbf` vs `\CJKfakebold`) or do I need to make separate macros?

Comment: @pg-robban: `\textbf` does not change Chinese characters, if you don't set `BoldFont` feature. And maybe you didn't notice that `\CJKfakebold` does not change Latin characters, as is shown above. You can use `\CJKfakebold{\textbf{正确的粗体 Bold}}` safely.

Comment: Aha, I got it now :) 麻烦您了，thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

This is a know [XeTeX bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/61/), I don’t think there is currently a way to fix it.