# Draw border of a line

Tags: asymptote, rounded-corners

I have a line like this:

`line.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}

\begin{asy}
unitsize(1cm);
defaultpen(0.5cm);

draw((0,0)--(1,1));
\end{asy}

\end{document}
```

`latexmrc`:

```
sub asy {return system("asy '$_[0]'");}
add_cus_dep("asy","eps",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","pdf",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","tex",0,"asy");
```

As expected, it draws a solid line with rounded edges like this:

[image]

However, I would like to draw just the outer border of that line, something like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Sorry I don't know much about Asymptote, but what you provided produces no output for me.  Is there something special I need to run when using Asymptote, besides `pdflatex`?

Comment: I also have the `latexmrc` file with some code in it, will edit in a sec.

Comment: A user here, Malipivo, has used a `\pdfliteral` feature to do outlines of glyphs, which may apply in your situation.  Here are some examples: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169636/proper-outline-in-devanagari-and-arabic-fonts, and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18472/tikz-halo-around-text/169549#169549.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Can't seem to make that work with a line in asymptote.

Comment: I don't have `asymptote` on my system, but I reduced Malipovo's code down to the essentials, if that helps in an adaptation: `\documentclass{article}
\input pdf-trans
\newbox\qbox
\begin{document}
\def\maltext{\Huge$-$}
  \setbox\qbox=\hbox{\maltext}%
  \boxgs{Q q 2 Tr 0.4 w 0 0 0 RG 1 1 1 rg }{}%
  \copy\qbox
\end{document}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have taken the idea in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246403/draw-multiple-curves-at-a-constant-distance-from-one-another-in-asymptote), using the `graph` package to construct the `path[] getBorder(path, pen)` function as shown in the following code.

```
unitsize(1inch);
import graph;

path[] getBorder(path p, pen origPen)
{
    real offset = linewidth(origPen)/2.0/72.0;
    pair offsetPoint(real t) { return point(p, t) + offset*(rotate(90)*dir(p,t)); }
    path path1 = graph(offsetPoint, 0, length(p), operator ..);
    offset = -offset;
    path path2 = graph(offsetPoint, 0, length(p), operator ..);

    path[] paths;
    if (cyclic(p)) { paths = path1^^path2; }
    else { paths = path1..reverse(path2)..cycle; }

    return paths;
}

pen origPen = 10+black;

draw(getBorder((0,0){E}..{S}(2,0), origPen), red);
draw(getBorder((0,1)--(1,0), origPen), blue);
draw(getBorder(shift(1,0.5)*scale(0.5)*unitcircle, origPen), green);
```

[image]

The code works for cyclic or non-cyclic paths.  The `origPen` definition determines the resulting width of the path outline.  The function assumes that the `origPen` is defined with a `roundcap`.

Unfortunately, the nature of the function means that sharp corners or small radii will not be treated properly.  Maybe someone else knows how to overcome this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can over-draw it using a pen with the background colour and a slightly narrower width.

Here's an example: (compile with `asy` or integrate into your existing LaTeX doc).

```
unitsize(1cm);
guide sausage = (0,0) -- (2,3);
draw(sausage, black+5);
draw(sausage, white+4.2);
```

this produces:

[image]

The `draw(*guide*, *pen*)` command draws the `guide` with the specified `pen`.  To set the width of your pen, you just add a real number to an existing pen.  In this case I've used the predefined (coloured) pens `black` and `white`.  Adding 5 to `black` makes a pen that's 5 PostScript points wide.  If you wanted one that's 5mm wide then you could do `black+5mm` thanks to the clever way that Asymptote deals with units.

Comment: That almost works, but the problem is I need to make these overlap each other, which doesn't work with this approach.

Comment: OK, perhaps you can update the question to say that?

Comment: Getting the outline of a stroked path is hard -- I don't think it's implemented in Asymptote (but I'm not an expert).  You would certainly find it easier to define oval paths and draw them directly.  Could you try that approach?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the size of `defaultpen` to something less that what you are using, i.e., less than `0.5cm`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I'm trying to draw the region within a certain length of the line, not what you are doing.